# Tabulator PUT via Ajax to Django REST Endpoint - Reduces Table to Last Edited Record

Tags: django, tabulator

I am using Tabulator with Django to edit a model. After any change to a cell, I use setData to make an Ajax call to a REST endpoint created using Django REST Framework. The database updates ok. The problem is that the response from the server contains only the single record that was updated, and this is making the Tabulator data reduce to only that record.

My question is, how can I get Tabulator to disregard the response, or otherwise have the data be left alone following the edit?

I am pretty new at this stuff (both Django and especially JavaScript) so apologies if I've missed something basic.

My tabulator code is below.

1. The `function getCookie` is to generate a CSRF_TOKEN as per the instructions in the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-and-csrf-cookie-httponly-are-false). This is then included in the `header` as `'X-CSRFTOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN`.
2. The variable `ajaxConfigPut` is used to set the method to PUT and to include the CSRF_TOKEN as noted above. This is then used in the `table.setData` call later on (`table.setData(updateurl, updateData, ajaxConfigPut);`).
3. The function `ajaxResponse` at the end just checks if the response is an array or not (because Tabulator expects an array which is fine for GET, but the PUT response was only a single {} object. So this function forces the PUT response into an array consisting of one object `[{}]`.

```
    <div id="example-table"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // get CSRF token
        // https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-and-csrf-cookie-httponly-are-false
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
                }
            }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }

        var CSRF_TOKEN = getCookie('csrftoken');

        // set variable to customise ajaxConfig for use in the setData call
        var ajaxConfigPut = {
                method:"PUT", //set request type to Position
                headers: {
                    // "Content-type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //set specific content type
                    'X-CSRFTOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN,
                },
        };

        //create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
            ajaxURL:"{% url 'cust_listapi' %}", // reverse pick up the url since in a django template (?)
            height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
            layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
            columns:[ //Define Table Columns
                {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150, editor:true},
                {title:"Age", field:"age", hozAlign:"center",editor:true},
                {title:"Age_Bar", field:"age", hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress"},
                {title:"Customer Status", field:"is_customer", hozAlign:"left"},
                // {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
                // {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center"},
            ],
            // see http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/components#component-cell
            cellEdited:function(cell){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
                console.log("Cell edited in row " + cell.getData().id 
                        + " and column " + cell.getField()
                        + " from " + cell.getOldValue() + " to " 
                        + cell.getValue()
                        + ". The row pk=" + cell.getData().id 
                        );
                console.log(cell.getData());

                var updateurl = "{% url 'cust_listapi' %}" + cell.getData().id + "/"
                console.log('URL is: ' + updateurl)
                // Create variable from full row data but drop the id;
                console.log('About to create updateData')

                var updateData = {};
                updateData[cell.getField()] = cell.getValue();

                console.log(updateData);

                console.log('About to setData');
                table.setData(updateurl, updateData, ajaxConfigPut);
                console.log('Finished setData');
                //cell.restoreOldValue();
            },
            ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
                console.log('Beginning ajaxResponse')
                console.log('The type is:', typeof(response));
                console.log(Array.isArray(response))
                console.log(response)
                result = response;
                if(Array.isArray(response) === false){
                    result = [response];
                };
                return result;
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Here's a screenshot of the table before editing:
[Table Before Editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldxEG.png)

And here's a screenshot after editing the top row (changing 'Mabel' to 'Jemima'):
[Screenshot after editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH1id.png)

And here's the console log:
[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fady.png)

I tried amending the response from the endpoint so that all records from the database are returned, but the problem with that is it doesn't include the edit, so the Tabulator table data is overwritten. Here's the code I used in the Django views.py. Maybe there's a way to return the data that has been changed?
**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins

from apps.app_mymodel.models import Customer
from .serializers import CustomerSerializer

class CustomerListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()

class CustomerUpdateAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView,
                            mixins.ListModelMixin,
                            mixins.UpdateModelMixin):

    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()

    # Override the put function here to return all records
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here's the serializer:
**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from apps.app_mymodel.models import Customer

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the Mixins used by your `CustomerUpdateAPIView` have a method called `put`. I don't think that function is called. Instead, you can try to override the `update` method of your viewset. It could look like this:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)  # performs the update operation
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You can check out this URL to understand the classes you are using: http://www.cdrf.co/
There you will see all the methods of the classes you are using to better understand the flow of your request.

Comment: Thank you! Your code worked perfectly. You were right - I had previously been using `generics.UpdateAPIView` which has a `put` method and forgot to change when I shifted to using mixins.

Comment: In those cases, always add a print() statements in that method to see, if it is actually called. Happens to me all the time, so by default, when developing, I add a print statement at the beginning of the method. Once I'm done, I remove them.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tip.