# Tabulator PUT Response Overrides Table Data

Tags: tabulator

When raising an Ajax PUT request from Tabulator, the response overrides the Tabulator table. I would have expected that for a PUT request, the response would not override the entire table. After all, the data that was changed is already reflected in the table. Since most PUT responses are a single object (the one that was changed), the table is reduced to a single row.

My question is: is it possible **in Tabulator** to make the PUT response **NOT** override the entire table?

This is a follow-on (hopefully not a duplicate) to [Tabulator PUT via Ajax to Django REST Endpoint - Reduces Table to Last Edited Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495898/tabulator-put-via-ajax-to-django-rest-endpoint-reduces-table-to-last-edited-re). In that question, the accepted answer was to change the reponse on the server side so that the full data set was sent, instead of just a single record. This will be a problem for large data sets.

I'm new to StackOverflow, so if I should re-open that question and close this one, please let me know.

The code for the Tabulator setup is below:

```
   <div id="example-table"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // get CSRF token
        // https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-and-csrf-cookie-httponly-are-false
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
                }
            }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }

        var CSRF_TOKEN = getCookie('csrftoken');

        // set variable to customise ajaxConfig for use in the setData call
        var ajaxConfigPut = {
                method:"PUT", //set request type to Position
                headers: {
                    // "Content-type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //set specific content type
                    'X-CSRFTOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN,
                },
        };

        //create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
            ajaxURL:"{% url 'cust_listapi' %}", // reverse pick up the url since in a django template (?)
            height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
            layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
            columns:[ //Define Table Columns
                {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150, editor:true},
                {title:"Age", field:"age", hozAlign:"center",editor:true},
                {title:"Age_Bar", field:"age", hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress"},
                {title:"Customer Status", field:"is_customer", hozAlign:"left"},
                // {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
                // {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center"},
            ],
            // see http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/components#component-cell
            cellEdited:function(cell){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
                console.log("Cell edited in row " + cell.getData().id 
                        + " and column " + cell.getField()
                        + " from " + cell.getOldValue() + " to " 
                        + cell.getValue()
                        + ". The row pk=" + cell.getData().id 
                        );
                console.log(cell.getData());

                var updateurl = "{% url 'cust_listapi' %}" + cell.getData().id + "/"
                console.log('URL is: ' + updateurl)
                // Create variable from full row data but drop the id;
                console.log('About to create updateData')

                var updateData = {};
                updateData[cell.getField()] = cell.getValue();

                console.log(updateData);

                console.log('About to setData');
                table.setData(updateurl, updateData, ajaxConfigPut);
                console.log('Finished setData');
                //cell.restoreOldValue();
            },
            ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
                console.log('Beginning ajaxResponse')
                console.log('The type is:', typeof(response));
                console.log(Array.isArray(response))
                console.log(response)
                result = response;
                if(Array.isArray(response) === false){
                    result = [response];
                };
                return result;
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Could you post your code for the Tabulator setup? It will help provide you an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the question and added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cellEdited callback, you are using table.setData. That is used to replace all the data. You should be using table.updateData to only update the affected row. You will need to add the id to the object. (Check the link below for the docs.)

Calling table.updateData will not trigger a request to your backend. You need to do that separately with fetch, xhr, or some other method.

Here is a link to the updateData page, http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/update.

If you need additional clarification or an example, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I don't know how to use fetch yet, but hopefully won't take too long to learn. I'll update here once I've tried this out. In the meantime, do you know what is the use case rationale for having setData able to send a PUT (or POST) request via Ajax, but then requiring the entire data set to be returned and updated? I'm not complaining - just interested to understand how it is intended to be used.

Comment: I used fetch and got it working. Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: It’s able to send other methods for flexibility on the backend. A backend may not be a standard REST api, so in that case Tabulator can be configured to use other http methods.

Comment: you can call the update function directly on the row component, cell.getRow().update({}) then there is no need to reference the row by id or anything else

Comment: @dr_cornelius, can you post the sample code you used for fetch? I'm new to the tabulator.